# How to calculate Pacing time in load runner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I have to run 100 iterations with 50 users. The total duration of the test is 1 hour. 1 user can do 2 iterations and the number of transactions in the script is 6.

How to calculate pacing time?

Answer (score 1):

Example:

1000 Users, 10000 Full Iterations per hour

10,000/1,000 = 10 iterations per user per hour

3600 seconds per hour /10 iterations per user per hour = one iteration every 360 seconds ( six minutes ) on average

The random algorithm in LoadRunner is based upon the C rand() function, which is approximately (but not exactly ) uniform for large datasets.  So, I take the average pacing interval from the start of one iteration to the next and then adjust it by plus/minus 20%.

So, your 360 ( 0:06:00 ) second pacing becomes a range from 288 seconds (0:04:48) to 432 seconds (0:07:12 ).

You would run these calculations for each business process you want to stage

For think time look to your production logs for information on the range of users from page X to Page X+1.  This is easily achievable since each top level page refers to the REFERER, or previous page that it came from.   A comparison of the timestamps grouped by client IP can provide that range you need for think times.

Comment: Can u tell me brodly

Comment: I just did. by example

Answer (score 1):

Always Apply Little's Law for calculate Pacing, ThinkTime, No.of VUsers

From Little's Law: **No of VUsers= Throughput*(Responce_Time + Think_Time)**

Expl.

*Throughput= Total No of Transactions/Time in Seconds
, Pacing= (Response_Time + Think_Time)*

From Your Requirements-
Total No of iterations 100 and 1 iteration have 6 transactions, So total no of transactions = 600

Throughput for 1 Minute is: 600/60 = 10
, Throughput for 1 Sec is: 0.16

According to formula 50 = 0.16*(Pacing)
Pacing = 312.5 seconds

To achieve 100 Iterations in 1 Hour you have to set pacing 312.5 seconds, Make sure Pacing = Response_time + Think_Time.

Answer (score 1):

Pacing is the 'inter-iteration' gap and it is used to control the rate of iterations during the test. If the goal for 1 user is to complete 2 iterations per hour, that results into a Pacing of 1800sec (little's law mentioned above) . Now as long as the summation of resp times of those 6 transactions and think time between them is less than 1800s, you will be able to achieve the desired rate.
NOTE: iteration is not equal to transaction, unless the iteration has just one transaction. Refer this to get a pictorial understanding

https://theperformanceengineer.com/2013/09/11/loadrunner-how-to-calculate-transaction-per-second-tps/

Comment: @satish: Sudhakar's requirement is to generate 100 ITERATIONS per hour so you have to use this number to calculate pacing regardless of the number of transactions in an iteration

Answer (score 0):

Pacing is the wait time between iterations so i'm agree with @CyberNinja, in your use case pacing is 1800s because it's the max duration of your script that achieve your goal : produce 100 iterations with 50 users in a hour.
Pacing is not Response_time + Think_Time!

Answer (score 0):

According to Little's Law :

```
No. of Concurrent Users(N) = 
    Throughput or TPS(X) * [
        Response Time (RT) + Think Time (TT) + Pacing (P)
    ]
```

Here `RT+TT` is Script Execution Time `SET` which you can calculate by running script once and adding up all the `RT` of transactions and all think times.

Assume `SET` to be 60 seconds.

As per your question

```
total transactions in 1 hr = 
    100(Iterations) * 
    50(Users) * 
    2(Each User Iteration) * 
    6(No. of Transactions)
= 60000 Transactions/hr
```

Converting it to `TPS = 60000/3600 = 16.66`

Now Putting all values in Little's Law:

```
50 = 16.66 (60 - Pacing)
Pacing = 60 - 50/16.66
Pacing = 57 secs (approx).
```