# Worload modelling -Calculate number of users and think time for load testing

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing

I want to know how to calculate number of users, Think time, Pacing time and number of Iteration for load testing.

Requirement is:

1. I need to achieve 10000 transaction per hour.
2. Need to do 1 hour execution.
3. My script contains 7 transactions.
4. Overall Response time is 16 sec without think time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your load testing tool the functionality to execute 10000 transactions per hour can already be there, for example in [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) there is [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer/)

If it's not there - the calculation would be something like:

1. I user executes 7 transactions in 16 seconds
2. It means that in 1 hour a user will execute 225 transactions, so you need to put 225 iterations in your load config.
3. Given you want to execute 10000 requests - you will need 10000/225 = 44.4 users for this.

If you're going to use more than 44.4 users - you will need to adjust pacing accordingly using i.e. this [Pacing Calculator](https://www.perfmatrix.com/pacing-calculator/) or [this formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38307587/2897748)